# How to use await on document.exitFullScreen method in javascript or react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to exit fullscreen on clicking a button...and use await to wait for the exit to happen...

below is the code,

```
class component1 extends React.PureComponent {
    handle_click = () => {
        document.exitFullscreen();
        this.other_method();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handle_click}>button</div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to call this.other_method only after the fullscreen is exited completely using await...

how can i do it. could someone help me fix it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use async/ await like below:

```
class component1 extends React.PureComponent {
    handle_click = async () => {
        try{
           await document.exitFullscreen();
           this.other_method();
        }catch(error) {
           alert(error);
        }


    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handle_click}>button</div>
        )
    }
}
```

In order to use await you will have to tell that function is using await, by using the async keyword.
For more details: visit [MDN docs for async fnction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Also, according to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitFullscreen) document.exitFullscreen() returns a promise. which can be handled by then() and catch() as well.

Comment: Edited the answer try it now. If promise will be success full then it will execute the other_method, or it will go to catch block.

Answer (score 2):

`document.exitFullscreen` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

You are able to run code afterwards using `.then` on the promise.

```
document.exitFullscreen().then(() => {
    // Code you want to do afterwards.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitFullscreen), `document.exitFullscreen()` returns an `exitPromise`. You can use `await document.exitFullScreen();` using async functions or just use the promise directly `document.exitFullscreen().then(() => this.other_method()).catch(() => true)`

Answer (score 0):

Handler can be async function:

```
    handle_click = async () => {
        await document.exitFullscreen();
        this.other_method();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handle_click}>button</div>
        )
    }
}
```